# Save and reload button on View (where is the error ?)

Tags: iphone, ios

sorry if I repeat the question, but being new I still have to learn your rules on how to respond and so on. 
Thanks to your help I got to this point:I can create 10 different buttons through AddButton on my UIView. When I close my application again, the 10 buttons disappear. then my user is forced to recreate the 10 buttons. 
How can I save the buttons created from my user?

I would use this method better since it can be useful if I have to use other date

I HAVE User data to file successful: YES

But do not go!

If I close and relaunch the application the buttons do not reappear

where is the error ?

EDIT MY FILE .h IN THIS WAY

```
{
    IBOutlet UIButton * button2;
    IBOutlet UIButton * Button1;
    IBOutlet UIButton * Button2;
    IBOutlet UIButton * Button3;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray * myArray;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton * Scenario1;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton * Scenario2;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton * Scenario3;
    - (IBAction) Button1: (UIButton *) sender;
    - (IBAction) Button2: (UIButton *) sender;
    - (IBAction) Button3: (UIButton *) sender;
```

ON FILE .m

```
     @synthesize myArray;
     @synthesize Button1;
     @synthesize Button2;
     @synthesize Button3;

     -(void) AddButton: (UIButton *) sender {
     CountButton + +;
     if (CountButton <11) {
     button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
     button2.frame = CGRectMake (20, 80, 120, 80); 
     UIImage *ButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @ "image"];
     [Button2 setBackgroundImage: ButtonImage forState: UIControlStateNormal]; NSString * buttonTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "Button% d", CountButton];
     [Button2 setTitle: buttonTitle forState: UIControlStateNormal];
     NSString *selectorName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "% d ButtonAdd:" CountButton];
     [Button2 addTarget: self action: NSSelectorFromString (selectorName) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     NSArray * = documentDirectories NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSMutableString * documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex: 0];
     NSArray * myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: Button1, Button2, Button3, nil];
     NSString * filePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @ "UserButtons"];
     BOOL FileError = [myArray writeToFile: filePath atomically: YES];
     NSLog (@ "User date to file successful:% @", (FileError? @ "Yes": @ "No"));
     }
     }

    -(void) viewDidLoad {
    [Super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray * = documentDirectories NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSMutableString * documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex: 0];
    NSString * myPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @ "UserButtons"];
    NSArray * fileArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: myPath];
    if ([fileArray count]> 0)
    {
     // Place your buttons back into the view.
     [Self.view addSubview: [fileArray objectAtIndex: 0]];
    }
    }
```

Comment: well you can simply take an array of added button.... and check in view did load if([addedButtonArray count]) then add all buttons from added button array one by one... if not then do nothing... and after everytime when u add button just add it in array also. Lastly before exiting/background from app just save it in userdefaults

Answer (score 0):

A file name is missing in what you have written.

Try to save datas with something like this :

```
NSString *myFile = @"myFile.plist";
NSArray *filePaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [filePaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:myFile];
[myArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: NP , I don't understand how to make ?

Comment: but it possibile that there no I can help ?
Wanted desperately Developer with a good Heart

Comment: The 4  first lines create the path to a file "myFile.plist". The last line permits you to write something in it (in your case an array). You can recover the datas in this same file by writing : `myArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];`